# How can we find the exact elements of 2 sets, A and B when they seem disjoint but their intersection is a given non-empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can we find the elements of 2 sets A and B if A-B={1,5,7,8}, B-A={2,10} and A∩B = {3,6,9}.

Now we know what A-B = A and B-A = B. Is it really possible here that A∩B could be a non-empty set? I would like to discuss this question in detail. Thank you

Comment: Why does A-B = A ?

Comment: @turkeyhundt A-B = A because A-B is the set of those elements that are a member of set A but not B. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Your definition is correct, but not the equation.  If A={1,2,3} and B={3} then A-B={1,2}.  $A-B\neq A$

Comment: The problem might be easier if you draw a Set Diagram with overlapping circles.

Comment: @turkeyhundt So you mean Venn diagrams. Right! That does seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Venn Diagram shows that A = {1,3,5,6,7,8,9} and B={2,3,6,9,10}.

[image]

Comment: Now i wonder if this same question can be solved by any method other then using Venn Diagram? Is is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things that are ***always*** true for any sets $A,B$:

- $(A\cap B)\cup(A\setminus B)=A$ ($A$ is the set of elements of $A$ that are also elements of $B$, together with the elements of $A$ that are *not* elements of $B$
- $(A\cap B)\cap(A\setminus B)=\emptyset$ (elements of $A$ cannot simultaneously be elements of $B$ and not elements of $B$)

We can also swap $A$s for $B$s (and vice versa) in both of the above statements, and obtain another true statement.

The first fact shown (and its $A$-to-$B$-swap version) will allow you to compute $A$ and $B$.